# passing properties argument for gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to submit a pyspark job to google cloud dataproc via the command line 
these are my arguments;

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster mongo-load --properties org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0 mongo_load.py
```

I am constantly getting an exception

```
--properties: Bad syntax for dict arg: [org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0]
```

I tried some of the escaping options from google shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping) but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured out I just needed to pass

```
spark.jars.packages=org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @Marlon Gray, if you need to pass more that one package you need to escape the `spark.jars.packages` string, like

```
--properties=^#^spark.jars.packages=mavencoordinate1,mavencoordinate2
```

Please check https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping for further details.